# angular: distance between two location

Tags: angularjs

I have two location coordinates. I need to check the distance between two coordinates. I searched and found some codes in PHP, C++, C# and Java.

I am using Angular1 and I need to make the calculation on the client side. So, I am looking for assistance in Angular. Here is the code that is written in JavaScript and I need to convert it to Angular.

```
    function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
                                return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
                              }

                              function distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
                                var earthRadiusKm = 6371;


var dLat = degreesToRadians(lat2-lat1);
                        var dLon = degreesToRadians(lon2-lon1);

                        lat1 = degreesToRadians(lat1);
                        lat2 = degreesToRadians(lat2);

                        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                                Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
                        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
                        return earthRadiusKm * c;
                      }
```

The problem is i never created a function in Angular. How can I start it?

I tried like this

```
$scope.distance = distanceInKmBetweenCoordinates($scope.userlatitude, $scope.userlongitude, $scope.mylatitude, $scope.mylongitude);

 alert($scope.distance);
```

It is giving me error:

> ReferenceError: distanceInKmBetweenCoordinates is not defined

Comment: Readers will need a [mcve] to be able to assist with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your controller:

```
function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
        return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
    }

function distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
        var earthRadiusKm = 6371;

        var dLat = degreesToRadians(lat2-lat1);
        var dLon = degreesToRadians(lon2-lon1);

        lat1 = degreesToRadians(lat1);
        lat2 = degreesToRadians(lat2);

        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        return earthRadiusKm * c;
}

$scope.distance = distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates($scope.userlatitude, $scope.userlongitude, $scope.mylatitude, $scope.mylongitude);
alert($scope.distance);
```

Comment: thanks, Fateme. I will try and will update you. I received downvote but you will get an upvote.

Comment: I tried the above code and it is already inside controller. It is giving me same error.

Comment: @Ironic it works fine, i opened a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WUXdsHWJGTRnLDOIPUZk?p=preview).

Comment: @Ironic did you check the plunker?is there any error?

Comment: Your code is fine. I am facing issue with cordova Deviceready. Function is firing before it loaded.

Comment: if i put value manually then it is working fine but when i pass value from angular scope then it is giving me same error.

Comment: @Ironic i think you do this in a wrong way would be good if you post your code.